# How to upload pictures to firebase in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic4

I'm unable to upload images to firebase.  Any help would be appreciated.

Is anyone familiar with how to upload pictures to firebase in Ionic 4.0?  Below is the code that use to work in Ionic 2, but now when I click the button to upload an image to firebase it takes approximately 30 seconds to respond to the (click) and then it never uploads the image to firebase.

I tried using the example in this tutorial but I can't get rid of the errors related to ImagePicker.  https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-firebase-image-upload
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
      <ion-card-content>
            <div>
                <img src="assets/img/add-an-image.png" (click)="selectPhoto()"/>     
            </div>
        </ion-card-content>
```

```js
constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private camera: Camera) {

        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        this.userId = user.uid;
        this.myPhotosRef = firebase.storage().ref(`/Photos/${ this.userId }/`);
      });
    }

  selectPhoto(): void {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      console.log(options, 'get pic');
      this.myPhoto = imageData;
      this.uploadPhoto(this.myPhoto);
    }, error => {
      console.log('ERROR -> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }

  private uploadPhoto(photoName: string): void {
    this.myPhotosRef.child(photoName)
      .putString(this.myPhoto, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/png' })
      .then((savedPicture) => {
        this.myPhotoURL = savedPicture.downloadURL;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You say, `"I tried using the example in this tutorial"`. What tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-firebase-image-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully upload images to firebase using the following tutorial:

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/building-a-ionic-firebase-app-step-by-step

Answer (score 2):

**Image upload on Firestore in Ionic 4 app**

Check this tutorial link

https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-image-upload-with-progress-in-firestore-and-firestorage-tutorial-by-application/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is really a lot of ways to do this, you can use the response and errors to track what is going on. Enable the web console log.

Here is a example of how to do it and track the errors:

```
uploadFile(file){
const fileName = this.generateRandomName() + '.jpg';
const fileRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('tptimagefolder/'+ fileName);
const uploadTask = fileRef.put(file);

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
},  error => {
      reject(error);

}, () => {
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('teste resolve url'+downloadURL);

    resolve ( {fileName, downloadURL});
  });

});

}); }
```

this.generateRandomName() is a function to create a name, you can use without it if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial from Ionic Themes to upload images to Firebase Storage: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-firebase-image-upload

It says it's for Ionic 3 but it also works in Ionic 4.

According to the tutorial, Storage is separate from firestore and the fire storage module, so in your app module, you have to import firebase like this:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
```